# "hands-on mentality" - what does it mean?

Tags: meaning

Some employers demand "hands-on mentality", it is often used in job descriptions. Can someone explain what exactly this phrase means?

Comment: It means they don't want you sitting there and thinking about a problem; they want you to be actively *doing something* to solve the problem.

Comment: [hands-on](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hands-on) is in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

> Hands-on mentality - The employers are looking for "practical
>   experience" or  "active participation" in the desired field.
>
> - “hands-on operations”
> - "hands-on manager"

Answer (score 0):

I have often heard the phrase, "Do something even if it's wrong."  Meaning, try even if you fail.

They are not looking for a philosopher.